# Python code won't run?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello i was wondering why this code will not run,thanks.

```
count = 0
finished = False
total = 0
while not finished:
    number = int(input("Enter a number(0 to finish)"))
    if number == 0:
        finished = True
        else:
            total = total + number
            count = count + 1
print("the average is", total/ count)
count = 0
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Welcome to [so], we are trying to create a repository of **good** Qs&As here. Please read at least the [tour] and bring some quality (by editing) to your current post. 1) Your post doesn't contain a question. It has a question mark tagged to a statement, that is not the same. 2) "Hello" and "Thanks" don't contribute anything to the clarity of the post, so leave them out. 3) Other people don't care about what you wonder about, believe, had for breakfast; it would be much more informative to include a sentence: Why does the following code throw the error 'ABC XYZ' when I run the program

Comment: 4) learn at least to format code correctly by selecting the **complete** block of code you pasted in and then hit the `{}` icon above the edit box. 5) use proper spelling for words like 'i', not everyone is a native speaker and understands written slang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is alright, you haven't indented properly the `else`clause, here's a working example, also, you should cast to float your average:

```
count = 0
finished = False
total = 0

while not finished:
    number = int(input("Enter a number(0 to finish)"))
    if number == 0:
        finished = True
    else:
        total = total + number
        count = count + 1

print("the average is", float(total) / float(count))
count = 0
```

Another possible way to do the same with few lines would be this:

```
values = []
while True:
    number = int(input("Enter a number(0 to finish)"))
    if number == 0:
        break

    values.append(number)

print("the average is", float(sum(values)) / float(len(values)))
```

Comment: If we're talking about few lines: `print(f"the average is {__import__('statistics').mean(map(int, iter(input, '0')))}")`. ;-)

Comment: @Veky Nice, I'll give you the upvote cos one of the tags of the OP was python-3.x ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It does run, the only issue I can see is that your else is indented inside your if block. In Python, indentation is important in a way that curled brackets or keywords are important in other programming languages.

```
count = 0
finished = False
total = 0
while not finished:
    number = int(input("Enter a number(0 to finish)"))
    if number == 0:
        finished = True
    else:
        total = total + number
        count = count + 1
print("the average is", total/ count)
count = 0
```